# How do I handle animated tiles without updating the arrays every frame?

Tags: arrays, opengl, buffer, textures

So I'm making an ascii game where each tile is

1. A glyph
2. A foreground colour (glyph colour)
3. A background colour

The glyphs are stored in a single texture.

To render them without animation, I've created a VAO with buffers for vertices, texture coords, foreground colour and background colour.

Now what I'd like to do is to put each animation frame (so texture coord, foreground colour and background colour) in buffers so that I don't have to upload them every time the animations update. Maybe use a uniform for time elapsed and derive the texture coords from that?

The problem is that these frames have differing length and numbers.

What's the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: "*I don't have to upload them every time the animations update*" You're making an ASCII-art game; the cost of uploading a few kilobytes of data per-frame will not be noticeable. You're going to have to upload data for UI rendering anyway, right?

Comment: You'll have to notify your graphics processor of the new data *somehow*, but switching vertex buffers a lot does not sound like the proper approach at all. Instead, since this is an ASCII game, consider just having a big grid of quads filling your screen, which you render in a single draw call, and change the texcoord and color buffers (initialized as GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW) as necessary using glBufferSubdata. That way you'll never have to change your VAO at all.

Comment: It may be even simpler to just overwrite the texcoord and color buffers entirely every frame with glBufferData, in which case you can also have more freedom as to the order, location and amount of quads you render if you replace the buffered vertices too (this method is also suited for non-grid-aligned sprite rendering). As @NicolBolas said, the impact will still be negligible.